# Amount of distance from the Jury?

Tags: united-states, rules-of-court

Having observed many jury trials, it seems that lawyers are only allowed to stand behind the podium or walk around the direct area around the podium (within 2 or 3 feet) while addressing the court.

In one instance a lawyer did try to stand within two feet of the jury box, and faced the jury, immediately the judge reprimanded the lawyer saying:

> You are here to address the court, not to directly address the jury

Are there specific rules of court etiquette that says a lawyer can't approach the jury (like the rules that a lawyer needs approval to approach the witness box)?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there specific rules of court etiquette that says a lawyer can't approach the jury (like the rules that a lawyer needs approval to approach the witness box)?

There are rules and directions to that effect, although these fall short of quantifying the minimum distance counsel should keep. For instance, [Montana 7th Judicial District Court Rule 18](https://courts.mt.gov/portals/189/dcourt/dc_rules/7th.pdf) states:

> 32. Attorneys have the responsibility of keeping themselves, their parties, and their witnesses apart from the jury at all times
> 33. During final argument, the attorney must stay a reasonable distance from the jury box.

See also section on *Decorum and Courtroom Management* [here](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20161109f83) and [here](https://www.leagle.com/decision/infdco20140513l36):

> Stand a respectful distance from the jury at all times.